# How to map void* in java

Tags: java, jna, can-bus

I'm trying to map the following C method provided from vxlapi.dll to java:

```
XLstatus xlCanTransmit (
XLportHandle portHandle,
Xlaccess accessMask,
unsigned int *messageCount,
void *pMessages)
```

My problem is related to **void *pmessages**, I tried to use the Pointer as indicated in the JNA mapping page but dll it seems to do not accept that type.
I need to pass a s_xl_event message that it is a structure so defined:

```
public class s_xl_event extends Structure {
    public class ByReference extends s_xl_event implements Structure.ByReference {}

    public byte tag;
    public byte chanIndex;
    public short transId;
    public short portHandle;
    public byte flags;
    public byte reserved;
    public long timeStamp;
    public s_xl_tag_data tagData;

    public s_xl_event() {
        allocateMemory(56); // vxlapi.h: s_xl_event requires 48 byte
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("tag","chanIndex","transId","portHandle","flags","reserved","timeStamp","tagData");
    }   
}
```

If I pass a s_xl_event item the dll is responding ok but it not works as expected, send all 0. With a pointer it returns XL_ERR_WRONG_PARAMETER.
Can you help me to understand what I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to write some wrapper functions in C. Things that are acceptable in C (a pointer to some undermined chunk of memory) don't work very well in Java.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to call that function?

Comment: NIO used `long` for pointers, with JNI.

Comment: When you say you "pass a s_xl_event item the dll is responding ok" are you defining the ByReference version of the structure?  Please post the code you are using to define the parameter that you pass to the xlCanTransmit function.

Comment: Also why are you explicitly allocating memory in the Structure? Does it not do that for you?

Comment: You may want to consider `LPVOID` (which is just a decorator class extending `PointerType`) in preference to `long` as suggested in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method called send where I do the following steps:

```
IntByReference pEventCount = new IntByReference(1);
s_xl_event eventMsg = new s_xl_event();

eventMsg.tag = 10; //  XL_TRANSMIT_MSG
eventMsg.tagData.msg.id = Long.parseLong(message.getID());
eventMsg.tagData.msg.dlc = (short) message.getSize();
eventMsg.tagData.msg.flags = (short) 0;
try {
    eventMsg.tagData.msg.data = Hex.decodeHex(message.getDefaultPayload());
} catch(Exception e) {}

eventMsg.write();

short status = driver.canTransmit(portHandle, accessMask, pEventCount, eventMsg.getPointer());
```

the method canTrasmit call the function defined in the interface that extends Library:

```
public short canTransmit(long portHandle, long accessMask, IntByReference messageCount, Pointer message) {
            short status = device.xlCanTransmit(portHandle, accessMask, messageCount, message);

        return status;
}
```

```
public interface VectorInterface extends Library {
short xlCanTransmit(long portHandle, long accessMask, IntByReference messageCount, Pointer message);
}
```

I suppose that Structure is already by reference as indicated in the API. I needed to allocate the memory because in the receive the assigned quantity (24) was insufficient and cause JVM crash.

Comment: You're allocating memory but never freeing it (at least not in the code you've posted).  `s_xl_event eventMsg = new s_xl_event();` This may cause problems for you -- there should probably be a corresponding `delete` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that structures are wrong placed and it were missing the static type. I rewrited the structure correctly but now I have the issue that inside s_xl_event all fields are filled except s_xl_tag_data. I don't know if it depends from the fact that it is an union of other structures...